# To reduce to nearly nothing (to make negligible)

Tags: single-word-requests

Using a single verb, I want to express the act of making something negligible, i.e. very small or insignificant. "Neglate" doesn't seem to be english :)

Example sentence:

*About the delay between two events in time. It should be possible to almost `<word here>` this delay.*

Second example, as some people didn't get what I intended.

*About cutting the cost of something. It should be possible to `<word here>` the cost.* And no, not minimize, it is really about cutting it all the way down to almost nothing, to something that is negligible.

Comment: In case this question isn't a joke, verb form of *negligible* is, of course, ***neglect***.

Comment: I found [an instance of ***neglibilize***](https://babblespeak.wordpress.com/tag/swami-chinmayananda/) by one "Swami Chinmayananda", who puts it in scare quotes to acknowledge that it's a neologism (apparently equivalent to ***tuchCham*** in some other language). And there's this guy (presumably British) who admits he's making up the word: [*It does seem like the white majority is trying to **negligibilise** (I know, I'm making up too many words) the black minority.*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=1sRrV933I-HR8gfgxYrgDg#q=%22negligibilise%22)

Comment: In the context stated, "ignore" is the most appropriate word.

Comment: @HotLicks it's not what I meant, so I added another example.

Comment: "Ignore" still fits.  (But this assumes you intended to type "It", not "I".)

Comment: @DanBron "neglect" is what you do with something, once it is negligible. But what do you do to make it negligible?

Comment: @HotLicks Ignore fits in the sentence, yes, but then it doesn't express something about the act of cutting, which is stated as required.

Comment: @DanBron Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough: Yes, "neglect" is what you do with something negligible, because it is negligible. But the original question is about the verb for the act of making something negligible and thus a valid object to being neglected in the first place. So "neglect" does not fit here, does it?

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Like in all *-ible*, *-able* words, here it indicates the property or characteristic of being *capable* or *worthy* of being neglected. Obviously if you neglect it, it is negligible, but it's not negligible because you neglected it: no, quite the contrary, you *neglected it because it is negligible*. The phrase "neglecting differences due to.." and similar is very common in exactly this sense in mathemetics and academia generally. As to OP's question, and your rephrasing "what do we do to make something negligible?", I dunno. Some potent synonym of reduce.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek Yeah, in retrospect I realized that's what you were saying. I tried to edit my comment to reflect that updated understanding, but the 5 minute comment-editing window expired before I could.

Comment: This is not an answer as it's not a word: *render negligible*   would be comfortable on the reader and convey the right meaning.

Comment: I just gave this a +1, because in computer science, you can "optimize away" or "optimize out" but I'm unaware of a standalone verb for that concept.

Answer (score 2):

*Mitigate* is probably not strong enough for this context. It means:

> *Make (something bad) less severe, serious, or painful* - [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mitigate)

The most suitable word, given that your example uses the modifier "*almost*", might be:

> **Eliminate** -- [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eliminate):
>   Completely remove or get rid of (something).

Hence:

> *'It should be possible to almost eliminate this delay.'*

Answer (score 2):

The word you are looking for is annihilate- it comes from the Latin nihil meaning nothing- to make nothing

Answer (score 1):

Since the idea here is that the effect of the thing is reduced to a negligible quantity, you can use the verb **obviate**.

> About the delay between two events in time. It should be possible to
>   almost obviate this delay.

Personally, I would drop the *almost*, you have gotten rid on the need to consider it.

> About cutting the cost of something. It should be possible to obviate the cost.

bold mine

> For instance, scientists may be within striking distance of plants
>   that would produce edible vaccines and insulin, a highly practical
>   means of distribution to developing states **that would obviate the cost
>   of transportation**, the need for refrigeration, and the dangers of
>   using needles.1

p13, http://scholarship.law.gwu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1896&context=faculty_publications

[image: https://books.google.com/books?id=BghIAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA24&img=1&pgis=1&dq=%22obviate+the+delay%22&sig=ACfU3U1UqRuQfWc79zHNHACPsYuZ7SD1lg&edge=0]

However, one note of caution is worth mentioning. *Obviate* is often used to refer to an indirect attack on the problem. It suggests that you change the game to make the issue irrelevant, more so than directly tackling the problem head-on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the impression that ***decimate*** and ***minimize*** are too weak,
and ***eliminate*** and ***eradicate*** are too strong, for what you want. 
You might want to just slam a couple of those together and coin a new word,
like ***minimize*** + ***eliminate*** → ***eminimate***. 
(Compare to ***[burninate](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/44273/origin-meaning-of-burninate)***,
which obviously derives from ***burn*** + ***eliminate***.)

Answer (score 1):

*It should be possible to **dwindle away/dwindle down** the cost*

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dwindle+away

> to shrink, contract, or diminish to something.

The phrase *dwindle away* is connotative of *reducing to nothing*, as evidenced in its frequent use in the larger phrase *dwindle away to nothing*: [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dwindle+away+to+nothing%22&oq=%22dwindle+away+to+nothing%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7418j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22dwindle+away+to+nothing%22&tbm=bks)

or *dwindle down to nothing*: [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22dwindle+away+to+nothing%22&oq=%22dwindle+away+to+nothing%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.7418j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22dwindle+down+to+nothing%22)

Answer (score 0):

'*negate*' seems appropriate here.

> It should be possible to almost *negate* this delay.

Comment: Can you add some citations for this word and link to your source please?

Comment: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/negate                                                                    *to nullify or cause to be ineffective*:
Eg. Progress on the study has been negated by the lack of funds.